# python: repeated expansion of dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

My dataframe is:

```
X=[0,1,2
   1,0,3
   2,3,0]
```

`X` shape is `3*3`.
For every value, I want to expand `n` times in every row and column, that is, transform my dataframe to the shape of `(3*n)*(3*n)`,
if `n=2`, my ideal result is:

```
X=[0,0,1,1,2,2
   0,0,1,1,2,2
   1,1,0,0,3,3
   1,1,0,0,3,3
   2,2,3,3,0,0
   2,2,3,3,0,0]
```

How to do that? thanks!

Comment: Would a NumPy-based solution work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using `pandas.Index.repeat`:

```
ind = df.index.repeat(2)
new_df = df.iloc[ind, ind]
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
   0  0  1  1  2  2
0  0  0  1  1  2  2
0  0  0  1  1  2  2
1  1  1  0  0  3  3
1  1  1  0  0  3  3
2  2  2  3  3  0  0
2  2  2  3  3  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [numpy.repeat](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html#numpy-repeat), as follows:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[0, 1, 2],
              [1, 0, 3],
              [2, 3, 0]] )
res = X.repeat(2, axis=1).repeat(2, axis=0)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[[0 0 1 1 2 2]
 [0 0 1 1 2 2]
 [1 1 0 0 3 3]
 [1 1 0 0 3 3]
 [2 2 3 3 0 0]
 [2 2 3 3 0 0]]
```

Comment: It works! But it needs `np.array()` and then `pd.DataFrame()` to transform the data type.

Comment: Could you be more specific, note that the X in your question is not a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

A base python solution (without imports) would be a nested list comprehension:

```
>>> [[y for y in x for _ in range(3)] for x in X for _ in range(3)]
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
 [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3],
 [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3],
 [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3],
 [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0],
 [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0],
 [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0]]
>>>
```